# Giving list of parameters in Payload

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary

I wanted to ask if there is a way to give a list of items for a certain parameter in the Payload. I have tried to look but been unable to find a way to give more than one parameter.
The sample is attached below. I have a list of thousands of ***postal_code*** values that I want to extract information of. Is there a way that I can give let's say 1000 or 5000 values at a time and extract their information.

```
payload = {'nar_only': '1','offset': '','limit': '300','marketing_area_cities':  '_',
           'postal_code': '','is_postal_search': 'true','name': 'john','types': 'agent',
           'sort': 'recent_activity_high','far_opt_out': 'false','client_id': 'FAR2.0',
           'recommendations_count_min': '','agent_rating_min': '','languages': '',
           'agent_type': '','price_min': '','price_max': '','designations': '',
           'photo': 'true'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the API, you need to look at the documentation if it supports batch query or if there is another endpoint that supports querying with multiple **postal_code** parameters.